# How to set the sign of a value based on another

Tags: php, algorithm, logic, negative-number

I am working with a php script which has a calculation that gives me a number. The calculation itself is a black box and I access it using a function which gives me a number back.

So:

```
$num = doCalc($some_arguments); //$num now has a non-zero numeric value
```

Now, I want the sign of `$num to be positive or negative` based on the sign of another number. I know I can do this with "if-else", but I am trying to check what is the best way to do it without logical branching.

So heres what I am doing to apply the sign of $anotherNum to $num:

```
$anotherNum = -10; //for example...
$num = doCalc($some_arguments); //lets assume $num is 100...
$num = abs($num) * ($anotherNum/abs($anotherNum))
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, or if PHP has functions that can make this easy to do. Any pointers, anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: I like the answer @Spektre gave, but if you _really_ wanted to avoid any kind of comparison logic then I like your approach. Maybe you could mitigate the precision issue by casting the division into an ingeger ? `$num = abs($num) * (int)($anotherNum/abs($anotherNum))`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in many ways, your approach can change the sum value precission (on floats) because of the multiplication and division ... here some more options let `a` be your `num` and `b` the `anothernum`

1. if multiply numbers with different polarity the result is negative

   ```
   if ((a*b)<0.0) a=-a;
   ```
2. avoid computations

   ```
   if (((a<0.0)&&(b>0.0))||((a>0.0)&&(b<0.0))) a=-a;
   ```
3. sign bit extraction

   - sign is usually the MSB of number for booth integer and flaoting values in most languages/platforms so in that case
   - for 32 bit floating values:

     ```
     unsigned int sa=(unsigned int*)(&a)[0]>>31;
     unsigned int sb=(unsigned int*)(&b)[0]>>31;
     if (sa!=sb) a=-a;
     ```
   - for 32 bit integer values:

     ```
     if ((a&0x80000000)!=(b&0x80000000)) a=-a;
     ```
   - does not matter if you bitshift or bit mask ...
   - for 64 bit values use 64 bit variable and change bit shift to 63
   - or add another 8 zeroes to the mask hex number

[notes]

- now you need just add the case when `b==0` ...

**[edit1] no if/else for floats**

```
float a,b; // these are you numbers
unsigned int *pa=(unsigned int*)(&a);
unsigned int *pb=(unsigned int*)(&b);
*pa=((*pa)&0x7FFFFFFF)|((*pb)&0x80000000);
```

- so then just copy the sign bit from `a` to `b`
- `pa,pb` are just pointers to handle a,b as integer type for bit acces
- first half clear the sign bit in a
- second copies the sign bit from b

Comment: thank you for your answer....however I am trying to do it without if/else conditions...

Comment: @UndefinedVariable the use of bit operations for floats is easy see [edit1] for integers is it possible only if your number has separate sign bit instead of 2os complement